# How to decreasing value based on other column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
ID_Client | Counter | Length | Amount | Date_From | Date_To
-------------------------------------------------------------
AAA         0         25       30      2015-01-09   2015-01-15
AAA         2         25       30      2015-01-15   2015-02-06  
AAA         2         25       30      2015-02-06   2015-03-10
AAA         1         25       30      2015-03-10   2015-04-12 
AAA         1         25       30
AAA         2         25       30
AAA         1         25       30
AAA         1         25       30
AAA         1         25       30
AAA         2         25       30      2016-04-01   9999-99-99 Infinity (last record for AAA at the moment)
BBB         0         30       60
BBB         1         30       60
BBB         2         30       60
BBB         2         30       60
```

### Value1 column:

Row1 of `Value1` = 1st row of `Counter`

Row2 of `Value1` =  1st row of `Value1` + 2nd row of Counter column etc.

### Value2 column:

Row1 of `Value2` = 1st row of Amount

Row2 of `Value2` = 1st row of `Value2` - 2nd  row of Counter column etc

The result should be grouped by ID_Client.  Value1 and Value 2 should be start counting again when is new client.

I need to get this table:

```
ID_Client | Counter | Length | Amount | Value1 | Value2
--------------------------------------------------------
AAA         0         25       30       0        30
AAA         2         25       30       2        28
AAA         2         25       30       4        26
AAA         1         25       30       5        25
AAA         1         25       30       6        24
AAA         2         25       30       8        22
AAA         1         25       30       9        21
AAA         1         25       30       10       20
AAA         1         25       30       11       19
AAA         2         25       30       13       17
BBB         0         30       60       0        60
BBB         1         30       60       1        59 
BBB         2         30       60       3        57
BBB         2         30       60       5        55
```

Thanks

Comment: What determines the order for these?  does order not matter?  or what is the PK of this table?

Comment: How do you define 1st row?

Comment: Looks like a very bad database design. So all records for an ID must have the same length and amount? There should be a client table instead with just one record per client ID containing these two values.

Comment: @PM77-1: At the beginning first row for each group of client have null but i changed using ISNULL to 0

Comment: @user2988195: So the first row is the one with counter NULL or 0. Okay. But which is the second, which the third? There is no column to indicate the records' order (like a datetime or the like).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: The length and amount may be change but it doesn't matter for the calculation in this case.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I edited table adding date_from and date_to column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e66e/16/0)

I assign row numbers as I need a unique value to order by and then we just sum value1 and subtract the amount from value1 more or less..

This uses a common table expression to create a result set with a row number and then an analytic function (window set) to generate a "running" total.

```
with cte as (
  Select ID_CLIent, Counter, Length, Amount, row_number()  
  over (partition by ID_CLient order by counter) RN
from foo)

Select ID_Client
     , Counter
     , Length
     , Amount
     , sum(Counter) over (Partition by ID_CLIENT order by ID_Client, RN) as Value1
     , Amount - sum(Counter) over (Partition by ID_CLIENT order by ID_Client, RN) as Value2 
  from cte c
  order by ID_Client
```

and now that we have a date to sort by I don't need the row numbers anymore...

```
Select ID_Client
     , Counter
     , Length, Amount
     , sum(Counter) over (Partition by ID_CLIENT order by ID_Client, Date_from) as Value1
     , Amount - sum(Counter) over (Partition by ID_CLIENT order by ID_Client, Date_From) as Value2
     , Date_from
     , Date_To
  from TableName 
  order by ID_Client, Date_From, Date_To
```

Comment: And now that we have a date.... you could get rid of the Row Num and substitute the Date_From as well as the Common table expression

Comment: Great job! :) Thanks!